# Contact form - Checking if the user had completed all the fields

Tags: php, forms, field, contacts

I have this contact form on my website, but I can't make it to check if the form fields were completed.

```
<form id="cform" name="cform" method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/cform.php">
  <div id="nande">
    <p><input type="text" id="name" name ="name"; onfocus="if(this.value=='Your Name is')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your Name is';" alt="Your Name" value="Your Name is"/></p>
    <p> <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="mail" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your Email is')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your Email is';" alt="Your Email" value="Your Email is"/></p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p><textarea name="message" rows="4" id="comments" tabindex="4" title="comments" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your Message is')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your Message is';"">Your Message is</textarea></p>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

Below is the PHP for the form

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $to = 'email@address.com' ;     //put your email address on which you want to receive the information
   $subject = 'designdone project email';   //set the subject of email.
   $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
   $message = "<table><tr><td>Your Name</td><td>".$_POST['name']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>E-Mail</td><td>".$_POST['email']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Message</td><td>".$_POST['message']."</td>
               </tr></table>" ;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header( 'Location: http://designdone.com' ) ;
}
?>
```

How can I check to see if the user completed the form and doesn't send an empty form?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I solved the problem using this form http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php It's the same concept used suggested by @editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) on the `$_POST` fields.

For example:

```
foreach ( $_POST as $attr => $val ) {
  if ( !isset( $_POST[ $attr ] ) || empty( $_POST[ $attr ] ) ) {
    die( 'Please fill out all fields.' );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I get this error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_EXIT' on the line with 'die' code.

Comment: you could write echo instead of die and use `exit();`

Comment: I solved the problem using this form freecontactform.com/email_form.php It's the same concept suggested by you. So thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a validation library.  There are many available, and most are very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you could use .isEmpty to determinate whether the field is empty or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in js. Can you tell me how to incorporate it into my code. I appreciate your time. Thanks.

Comment: Plain javascript is not my strong side (i personally prefer jQuery). But http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp should be enough for you to understand the basics and give you the idea of what to do (although isEmpty is not used there, there are other ways to validate fields).